# Add window size detection

Tags: css

My present code doesn't work and i have a unexpected token error :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myWidth = (window.screen.availWidth - 100);
    document.write("
        #test {
            width:" + myWidth +"px;
    }
    ");
    </script>
```

what's wrong ?

And, i would like to know if this is a correct way : i made a menu like http://blog.tomri.ch/super-simple-off-canvas-menu-navigation/ , displayed starting at the left ro the right, and i don't want to hide a button who has 100px width, (% width can't be appropriate). so, i do this for calculate width. It's a good way ? (i use html5/angularjs for android application).

Comment: why not use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) instead of js.  Also I don't think you can do a document.write over multiple lines like that

Comment: I don't know if you did this on purpose but Javascript doesn't work with unformatted multiline strings. This will give an unexpected token error.

Comment: `screen.availWidth` is the width of your entire monitor. You may want to have `window.document.body.offsetWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Proper way

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to return the available width of your screen.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = "Available Width: " + screen.availWidth + "px";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```